# Set up Logic Apps to execute stored procedures on multiple Azure server databases

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-logic-apps

I have a list of stored procedures (about 3) that I would like to set up in Logic Apps to execute on multiple Azure server databases. Is that even possible? The current setup only runs on one server and one database, as shown in the image below.
[image]

Comment: What have you tried and what issue have you encountered?

Comment: I'm new to Logic Apps, but basically, I try to run the same stored procedures across multiple servers and databases. The SPs set up staging tables for other applications to access. Some suggest adding a parallel branch within the workflows, but that still replicates the same stored procedures for each branch I create. What I have in mind is to set up variables for the servers and databases and then have the stored procedures loop through these variables, but I'm not sure how to do it or if that's even possible.

Comment: Create a new connection per step and point those new connections to the relevant DB’s/servers. Have you done that?

Answer (score 0):

In order to execute same store procedure across multiple servers, you need to create new connection in ***Execute stored procedure*** action for the relevant server/database.  Thanks **@Skin** for the comment.

Please make sure, store procedures are created in all the databases before executing it in logic app.

1. Add the first database connection in ***Execute stored procedure*** action and select the store procedure which you want to execute by providing the input value if required in **Parameters**.

**Store Procedure**-

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE FetchDatabaseName
    @ID INT,
    @Name VARCHAR(100) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT @Name = Name
    FROM [dbo].[Test]
    WHERE Id = @ID;
END;
```

[image]

2. To execute the store procedure in a different server, add a new connection as shown below.

**Click on change connection and then click Add new**.

[image]

[image]

Add the new connection details and click **create new** to create a new connection.

[image]

***Execute stored procedure 1*** action now points to a new connection.

[image]

**Output**-

I am able to execute it in the two different servers.

[image]

[image]

If you will add a third **Execute stored procedure**  action in your workflow and click on change connection then you can see already two connections are present. In the way, you can also add third connection to it by clicking on **Add new**.

[image]

Comment: thanks but I don't see how that works with multiple SPs. Unless I am misunderstanding your logic. Below is my current setup: I have a total of 3 workflows running at the same time. Each workflow executes the same SP, only on different databases and servers. My goal is to have only one workflow that executes the 2 SPs on three different databases and two servers simultaneously. These SPs already exist in the three databases.
1. Server North1
    - Db1
        * SP 1
 * SP 2
    - Db2
        * SP 1
 * SP 2
2. Server South1
    - Db5
        * SP 1
 * SP 2

Comment: @ATL-JP either you want to execute multiple SPs in same workflow on different servers or in different workflows on different servers, you need to create new connections as explained in my answer

Comment: Try to execute this logic at your end, if you get any error you can share the error message here